# i try to enter a value into an associative array, but it doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm making a form for an NGO (volunteer work) so they can let their members order some plants and whatnot.  Obviously that involves entering in some personal data.  What i'm trying to do is upon receiving the data from the form to walk over the `$_POST` array and assign all personal data to an associative array called `$klantinfo` (clientinfo).  I tried this first (only the else part matters):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    if (is_numeric($key) && is_numeric($value) && $value != 0){
        $aantalItems++;
        $items[$key] = $value;
    } else if(!is_numeric($key)){
        $klantinfo[$key] = $value;
}
```

that worked fine.  So i tried to add some checks on what was input (already did client-side validation) and reckoned i'd start simple.  So i made a switch like this:

```
switch($key){
    case 'lidnr': lidnr($value); break;
    case 'voornaam': voornaam($value); break;
    case 'naam': naam($value); break;
    case 'straat': straat($value); break;
    case 'gemeente': gemeente($value); break;
    case 'tel': tel($value); break;
    case 'email': email($value); break;
    case 'reedslid': lid($value); break;
    case 'afhaalpunt': afhaalpunt($value); break;
    default: break;
}
```

as an example of a simple function i called for one of those:

```
function lidnr($nr){
    if(mb_strlen($nr) == 6){
        $klantinfo['lidnr'] = (int) $nr;
        echo $nr;
    }
}
```

And for some reason that doesn't work, though it's beyond me why.  Originally i'd just declared the variable `$klantinfo` at the top of my script like this `$klantinfo;`.  I reckoned maybe it had to do with my declaration, so i tried it like this: `$klantinfo = array('lidnr' => 0, 'voornaam' => "", 'naam' => "", 'straat' => "", 'gemeente' => "", 'tel' => "", 'email' => "", 'reedslid' => 0, 'afhaalpunt' => "");`, doesn't work either.  Even weirder: if i go back to my initial code with that variable declaration and just use the `$klantinfo[$key] = $value` then all the items in the array $klantinfo that weren't filled in by the client are gone.  Even if i initialised those to a default value.

Am i missing something here?  I searched and read several threads.  Assigning a value to an associative array in php is supposed to be `$array['key'] = 'desired_value'`.  So why doesn't it work?  I should note btw that the echo you see in the example function i called does work.

Comment: "Doesn't work"? What *does* it do? Anything? Empty array? PHP error? Need more info about your code and issue (rather than the project background details ;) )

Comment: if i try to print_r $klantinfo using the initial "simple" technique then i got a nice list like this: Array ( [lidnr] => 654456 [voornaam] => Koen [naam] => Cornelis [straat] => Teirlinckstraat 50 [tel] => 0493635780 [mail] => koen@cornelis.be )

If i try that with the new technique i get nothing at all, just blank.

Comment: Are you sure that this condition is being met? `if(mb_strlen($nr) == 6)`, how about adding an `else` statement for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php): The array `$klantinfo` is not visible from within the `lidnr()`, `voornaam()`, etc. functions.

There are two ways of dealing with this:

1. Mark `$klantinfo` as global in each of these functions:

   ```
   function lidnr($nr){
       global $klantinfo;

       if(mb_strlen($nr) == 6){
           $klantinfo['lidnr'] = (int) $nr;
           echo $nr;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Strip the function and use it's body directly in the switch block:

   ```
   switch($key){
       case 'lidnr': 
       if(mb_strlen($value) == 6){
           $klantinfo['lidnr'] = (int) $value;
           echo $value;
       } 
       break;
   }
   ```

Comment: It would also be possible to [pass `$klantinfo` by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and manipulate it within the function. However that might not be handy as OP is having multiple functions ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty poor way of grabbing post data.  Iterating over the post, checking if it's numeric, reassigning to another array, iterating over that and doing a switch for each iteration to then pass a single value to yet another function.

Grab your post data explicitly from the $_POST array, validate it, and save.  Why is this so hard?  I would have added a comment, but I do not have enough karma.

Comment: i'm not grabbing it directly as there are 128 items that can be ordered, where most people will only order 1-5.  Items'll have a numeric key, everything else won't.  So i'm filtering in order to get rid of all the info in $_Post that i don't need.

I agree that it's a poor method.  But like i said, i'm new to PHP, i'm doing this as a favour and i'm honestly very short on time so i'm just going for what works quickly.  The only element i'm really researching thoroughly is how to secure the database to prevent SQL-injection.  I can optimise the code and learn PHP decently in february.